# hadoop /usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory

Tags: python, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to run a hadoop streaming server with following command from a shell script

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-0.19.2-streaming.jar -input $1 -output Twitter/Net.pegasus -mapper 'mapper.py Reverse' -reducer NONE -file mapper.py
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-0.19.2-streaming.jar -input $1 -output Twitter/Net.exclude -mapper 'mapper.py Reverse' -reducer reducer.py -file mapper.py -file reducer.py -file ../twitter/exclude.txt
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-0.19.2-streaming.jar -input $1 -output Twitter/Net.complete -mapper 'mapper.py Reverse' -reducer reducer.py -file mapper.py -file reducer.py
```

I am getting following error

```
/usr/bin/env: python2.5: No such file or directory
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

However the higher version of python is already installed

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

I read on some other post that by "apt-get install python2.5" it will work but that package isnt available and I also tried adding #!/usr/bin/env python to the top of my python script and it didnt work either

[Hadoop Streaming Job failed error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460522/hadoop-streaming-job-failed-error-in-python)

Comment: It looks like you have an executable python script that starts with this line: `#!/usr/bin/env python2.5`. In that case, there is supposed to be a binary called python2.5 that is invoked to run the script. Does that version of python exist on your machine? Run `/usr/bin/env python2.5` at the command line and see.

Comment: @hughdbrown I didnt had that version on my machine and one of the python scripts (mapper.py) was starting with this line: #!/usr/bin/env python2.5 so i just changed it to starts with this line: #!/usr/bin/env python and it worked. Thanks

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python` looks for `python` in the `PATH`. It not working when you have a `/usr/bin/python` on your filesystem implies that `/usr/bin/` is not in the PATH in the execution context where you start your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

Indicate you have a higher version of Python installed than default. You have to make sure this is the same case for every node in the cluster. For example, I work with a cluster Redhat 6.4 version cluster and the default Python is Python 2.6 I think as default, but I have customized the master node a bit and it is different from the datanode. 
So you need to configure your mapper to call a python that exist on every node.

put

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

at the beginning of the python script always work for me.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` will work if the user's PATH is empty (or doesn't include `/usr/bin`). On the other hand, they should probably fix that PATH; if their Python script tries to execute any other software, it's not likely to work with such a sparse PATH, so it's an issue worth addressing.