# Python cron job: /usr/local/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have the following crontab set up in a CentOS VPS:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/

* * * * * /root/ebay/findcheapitems.py
```

The script runs fine manually using:

```
python2.7 ebay/findcheapitems.py
```

It has been run through dos2unix for EOL conversion, has -rwxr-xr-x permissions, and first line of the file has:

```
#!/usr/local/bin python2.7
```

However I am getting mail every time the cron job attempts to run, saying:

```
/bin/bash: /root/ebay/findcheapitems.py: /usr/local/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I've confirmed the location of python2.7 using 'which':

```
# which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

I'm a linux beginner so I'm sure I'm missing something simple!

Comment: or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351241/hadoop-usr-bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory . Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You  need to specify the filepath as one path, not as directory and filename:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

Otherwise, the directory path is considered as an executable.

**UPDATE** As Kevin Guan suggested, you can also use `/usr/bin/env` instead of specifying the full path of the executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Comment: Also I'd suggest that use `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7` since it can search the `PATH` and run `python2.7`.

Comment: @KevinGuan, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Why linux could find the exact position even you just give a virtual path /usr/bin/env?

Comment: @cloudscomputes, `/usr/bin/env` is not a virtual path; it's a path to a program called `env`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/81068

Comment: OK,got it,Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

instead of `#!/usr/local/bin python2.7`